# NodeJS API NJS-003: invalid connection

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

First, i make an API using nodejs and oracledb.
I have 2 routes with different response time, let say route A with 10s response time and route B 1s response time. When i execute the route A followed by route B , i got the error **NJS-003: invalid connection** because route B finish and close the connection followed by route A.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

I'm using oracle pool , getConnection and close connection every API request.

```html
async function DBGetData(req, res, query, params = {}) {
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
    connection.callTimeout = 10 * 1000; 

    result = await connection.execute(
      query,
      params, 
      {
        outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT, 
      }
    );

    // send query result 
    res.json({
      status: res.statusCode,
      length: result.rows.length,
      results: result.rows,
    });
  
  } catch (err) { 
    return res.status(400).json({ error: err.toString() }); 
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      // Always close connections
      await connection.close(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `let connection;` before the `try` so that each `DBGetData()` invocation is definitely using its own connection.  Currently it seems that you are referencing a global variable.